# Can we schedule exe directly from TWS scheduler

Tags: scheduler, tivoli

For my project purposes, we need to schedule a job which invokes an C# exe file.

I know that we can have a batch file to invoke the exe file and schedule it using TWS.

I just want to know whether we can directly invoke an exe file from TWS

Comment: Am I meant to know this? What is "TWS"?

Comment: @JohnSaunders http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/tivoworksche probably. This is a case of bad tagging.

Comment: More a case of no tagging and of assuming shared context.

Answer (score 0):

TWS stands for Tivoli Workload Scheduler. It is now marketed by IBM as Tivoli Workload Automation.

Yes you can schedule a job which invokes an exe file. Basically, TWS emulates what a user is doing in a interactive session. If you can log to a server, start a command prompt and start you exe (and append arguments as needed), then TWS will do the same if you code the job right. It will provide you logs and return code handling too.